# Svn 1.5.x vs. latest version

Tags: svn, cvs, cvs2svn

Would I be missing out something really important (feature / optimization & speed) if I install SVN 1.5.2 instead of the latest 1.6.x?

Answer (score 2):

Not really, unless there is something important to you documented in [the 1.6 changelog](http://subversion.tigris.org/svn_1.6_releasenotes.html).

Comment: Careful though with working copies created with SVN 1.6. Or those which are accessed by both versions. SVN 1.6 changed the working copy layout (and this basically meant upgrading svn, TortoiseSVN, Subclipse and Ankh here. Not nice).

Answer (score 1):

I am using 1.4 still because Xcode ships with 1.4. I know that 1.5 had some big improvements, but in my experience it takes a long time for people to move to the new versions. Just make sure that your clients all support the version you are using. I had one automatically upgrade my working copy.

Answer (score 0):

You can safely use SVN 1.5.x. 
In fact most linux distributions are still on SVN 1.5 (e.g Debian lenny).

Most important features (client side):

- svn:externals for single files
- tree conflicts
- sparse directory exclusion

More important changes are on server side, which improve performance and repository handling

- packing complete shards
- logging support for svnserve
- examining history via browser

These features sounds promising, however none of these is as important as the merge tracking in svn 1.5.